# i can't add #region to .ashx in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

i create a generic handler (ashx) but i am trying to add region in my code like the following

```
 #region MyRegionName
   context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
   context.Response.Write("Hello World");
 #endregion
```

there is no error but the problem that there is no expand and collapse.

please any advice ?
note: i am using visual studio 2010

Comment: Provide a region name. `#region descriptionOfWhatThisRegionContains`

Comment: it still not work .. because #region in .cs file it show collapse event if there is no describtion

Comment: I've noticed this in asmx files as well.

Comment: i notice now that ashx not have a collapse even on anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hi i think i figure out the answer my self

in visual studio go to:

1- Tools -> option -> select Text Editor. 
2- in the right pane add an extension "ashx" and choose from the drop down list which editor u use .. i select microsoft visual c#. 
3- in the bottom check on "map extensionless to : the same selection above.
4- click ok and close the ashx page and reopen it.

thx every body for the answers

Comment: This isn't really a fix, it is a hack. All you are doing here is switching the default editor for ashx to the C# editor. You may get the regions working, but the editor will now start complaining about other aspects of the file that it doesn't see as valid C#. You are now basically using the wrong editor for the job.

Comment: Wow ! ... check out what breaks after this fix

Comment: it doesn't break that much it just break the ashx direct <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" ...

Comment: This isn't usable? No intellisense because the first line is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, see the explanation here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1162769.aspx#1928580.
The problem is, that the ashx file is not handled by the C# editor but by the ASP.NET editor.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Hang on a minute - I've just re-read your question. An .ashx file, like an .asmx or .aspx file is a *markup* file, not a code file. You can't use regions in these files. You can use regions in the *code behind* files associated with them (e.g. the .ashx.cs files) only.

**Original Answer:** Generally, whenever I get these sort of unexplained odd behaviours in VS2010, I reset all the settings, which normally resolves the issue.

Try Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset All Settings and see if that fixes your region issue.

If not, it may be related to a bad add-in or extension. Try disabling extensions/add-ins to see if that fixes your problem, alternatively try starting up in safe mode and see if the IDE behaves:

```
DEVENV.EXE /safemode
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no you can .. i just resolve the issue and i am writing the answer

Comment: no - your answer is really a hack that has other consequences. See my comment underneath.

Answer (score -3):

```
#region yourRegionName
//your code
#endregion
```